# Opensource for detecting running handwriting

Tags: open-source, detection, handwriting

Is there an open-source implementation in any programming language to detect running handwriting in English and convert them to text ?

Comment: Don't get your hopes up. I've looked around. I didn't find anything, but I didn't look very hard. Handwriting is *difficult*, due to all of the different styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is
[Ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)