# Free or affordable OCR and ICR (handwriting recognition) SDK?

Tags: forms, ocr, image-recognition, documents, icr

I'm looking to integrate OCR and ICR recognition functionality into a business app we're building to scan forms and other such documents. I've searched for hours and come up with Abbyy, IRIS and another few companies that market their SDKs with 4 figure prices. Do you know of any OCR/ICR engines that are free or affordable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opensource for detecting running handwriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130650/opensource-for-detecting-running-handwriting)

Comment: This is a duplicate strictly speaking, but I won't vote to close since the question was asked almost a year later and a new open source library for this could have surfaced.

Comment: After 6 years of this being posted, I still do NOT find a good solution. I need ICR as a service where I send a hand-writing form image and get some sort of JSON. This is still a great idea to make money!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Note that handwriting is a whole different ballgame.

Comment: IF handwriting and/or recognition of forms is needed then I suspect you are better off with specialized library (usually commercial...)

Answer (score 8):

While doing an educational app, we thought of integrating the handwriting recognition. After doing some research, here are three options that we found to be good. Probably there could be more options

1) Myscript from Vision objects -

Pro:- The software has one of the best recognition. 
Cons:- Sadly there is  no sales support. You have to keep chasing them to get a response. This is only from my personal experience. Infact, I got an appointment for a phone call and I stayed awake full night (due to time zone difference), but nope, no call came and neither an email. As this is only the pre-sales experience, we could just imagine how the post sales support would be. Hence we dropped them right away. But i do hope that this is one-off and only my experience and they are fine with others.

2) Phatware Writepad SDK  from Phatware

Pro - Another good software
Cons - It is not a con on them. Its just that it is out of our budget for now. I am putting this in because the Original poster of the question appears to be searching for a free SDK.

3) Lipi Tool kit from HP Labs India

Pro -  open source 
Cons - not available for iOS & limited languages

For now, we have decided to go with the Lipi for Android and wait for something good or affordable for us to be used on iOS.

Comment: You aren't alone with the horrible Myscript sales support experience. They are terrible.

Answer (score 4):

For ICR, I recommend using [MyScript from Vision Objects](http://myscript.com/) - there are live demos available on their site.